# Xcode target: Images from main target not loading in test target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

So, I've started using `FBSnapshotTestCase`, and everything is working as expected, except the images, that don't load correctly from the bundle. I have tested, and they are loaded in another bundle.

See debug details below:

```
(lldb) po [NSBundle allBundles]
<__NSArrayI>(
NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/.../Xcode/Agents> (loaded),
NSBundle </.../DerivedData/.../ProjectTests.xctest/Frameworks> (not yet loaded),
NSBundle </.../DerivedData/.../ProjectTests.xctest> (loaded)
)

(lldb) po [NSBundle mainBundle]
NSBundle </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/.../Xcode/Agents> (loaded)

(lldb) po [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]
NSBundle </.../DerivedData/.../ProjectTests.xctest> (loaded)
```

So when I run `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]` it returns `nil`, but when I run:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil]
```

It loads fine. But I can't go around changing all image loads in the app, and I don't know how to change it in storyboards. I've tried researching, and it's not possible to manually set the `mainBundle`.

Bottomline: Is there a target specific configuration to set the bundle for the target, or a way to create a script to move the assets to the correct bundle?

#### Edit:

I've verified that all assets have the test target checked, and that they are inside of `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase of test target. In fact, they are loaded, but somehow the main bundle is not what I'm expecting it to be

Comment: did you add images for test target too?

Comment: I feel a little stupid asking this, but should I copy them there? Can't I reference the main .xcasset?

Comment: During image drag & drop, Xcode asks for the targets to be selected. Ypu can choose your targets.

Comment: Oh, yes, all images have both targets checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the steps in [this guide](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) it started working fine, but I had to reconfigure some dependencies.
What I was missing was:

> 4) Click the Build Settings tab and set the Bundle Loader setting to $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyExistingApp.app/MyExistingApp
>
> 5) Set the Test Host build setting to $(BUNDLE_LOADER)